# Django REST framework rendering a field (or not) based on context

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've a Car class

```
class Car(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    engine = EngineSerializer(many=False, required=False)
    owner = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False)
```

and now I want to hide engine for users except the owner (this should be checked at `self.context['user'] == self.owner`.

I can accomplish this by making engine into a SerializerMethodField()

```
class Car(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    engine = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    owner = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False)
    def get_engine(self, obj):
        if self.context['user'] == self.owner:
            return EngineSerializer(self.engine, many=False).data
        else:
            return None or so
```

but this would create problems when creating + updating. What is the best practice for this? I don't aim privacy but just want to avoid cost of serializing the engine (imagine it takes a long time to serialize and it's useless for people except the owner)

Comment: you could create another serializer and use them based on you user, one serializer could inherit the other one for less code and in overall i think it would stay more MVC

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could use a custom field to handle this.

```
class EngineField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if self.context.get('user', None) == obj.owner:
            return EngineSerializer(obj.engine, many=False).data
        else:
            return None or so

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        do_something()


class Car(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    engine = EngineField()
    owner = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django Rest Framework is pretty easy to be extended, just look into internals :)

For example, if you are using any kind of view/view set that uses RetrieveModelMixin internally,
check out RetrieveModelMixin.retrieve() method. 
It calls GenericAPIView.get_serializer() method, passing object instance as a parameter.

You can override that method and return different serializer object based on the instance.owner field.

Once this method is changed in your view, this behavior will work for any mixins that operate on single object.

For queryset, it will be a bit more tricky, but I think if serializing an engine is costly, you would probably avoid serializing this field at all when returning a list of cars.

Sample code (not tested, and not perfect for sure, but you will get the idea):

```
class CarView(rest_framework.generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):


    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # instance returned by self.get_object is passed as first arg
        # in mixins used by RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
        car = args[0]

        if self.request.user == car.owner:
            serializer_class = ComplexCarSerializerWithEngineField
        else:
            serializer_class = SimpleCarSerializerWithNoEngineField

        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_object(self):
        ...
```